# How to make second identifier inside an array in mongodb document

Tags: mongodb, identifier

I am trying to make a collection of users,
each user has _id of MongoDB and name, mail and array of tasks and array of todos,
I want to have an identifier for each task and todo inside their arrays

Answer (score 0):

The arrays of tasks and todos could be an array of documents, so each task and todo could have an id and a value:

```
      {
    "name": "user1",
    "mail": "random@email.com",
    "tasks": [
      {
        "id": "taskId1",
        "task": "taskValue"
      },
      {
        "id": "taskId2",
        "task": "taskValue2"
      }
    ],
    "todos": [
      {
        "id": "todoId1",
        "todo": "todoValue1"
      },
      {
        "id": "todoId2",
        "todo": "todoValue2"
      }
    ]
  }
```

Comment: I want to increment it automatically when I do post/put, same for userid